# Xamarin.Forms Shell Navigation Hierarchy with parameters

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

How to define the following navigation hierarchy in a Xamarin.Forms Shell application?

- Navigation Tab (route "main")

  - Page with Orders List (route "orders")

    - Detail Page for one order (route "order", parameter "orderId")

      - Sub-Detail Page 1 for that particular order (route "details1", parameter "orderId")
      - Sub-Detail Page 2 for that particular order (route "details2", parameter "orderId")

It works well as long as there is only the `order` page without having the sub-detail pages defined. I can navigate then to that page via `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main/orders/order?orderId=5")` route.

But when I add the sub-detail pages (doesn't matter if I do this via XAML or `Routing.RegisterRoute`), the same `GoToAsync` call fails with `System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for: //main/orders/order?orderId=5'`

Hierarchy definition via XAML:

```
<Tab Title="My Orders" Route="main">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:OrdersListPage}" Route="orders">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:OrderPage}" Route="order">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:OrderDetailPage1}" Route="details1" />
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:OrderDetailPage2}" Route="details2" />
        </ShellContent>
    </ShellContent>
</Tab>
```

Same exception when I define it via custom routes:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("main/orders/order", typeof(pages:OrderPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute("main/orders/order/details1", typeof(pages:OrderDetailPage1));
Routing.RegisterRoute("main/orders/order/details1", typeof(pages:OrderDetailPage1));
```

Comment: Hi, it seems not works with four level of the `Route`, I will check that. If good ideas will update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround for this, you could `RegisterRoute` for the `third` and `fourth` level `Route` again in the **AppShell.xaml.cs**.

As follows:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("Order", typeof(OrderPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute("Details1", typeof(OrderDetailPage1));
```

Then can use the follow route path to navigate:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main/orders/Order/Details1?orderId=5")
```

If you Register the Route for each Page in `.cs` code, it will work. Generally, the first and second level if defined in `Xaml`, it seems not need to re-register in code again. Therefore, I only re-register the third and fourth `Route` with a name-key, not a path-key.

Comment: It's definitely a workaround but it seems to work. Even with back navigation :-) Many thanks!