# Xamarin.forms- pass object while navigation with Shell

Tags: shell, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin.ios

I am using shell and I want tabs on all the pages. so I am following standard way of shell navigation but the problem is I don't know how to pass an object along with the navigation.

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(page.ToString());`

doing this for navigation

`Routing.RegisterRoute("TesProject.Views.DetailView", typeof(DetailView));`

Registering Route like this

I want to pass a complete object from my list view to detail view. How can I do that?

[Xamarin.Forms Shell Navigation Hierarchy with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453803/xamarin-forms-shell-navigation-hierarchy-with-parameters)

I saw this but I don't think this will work in my case because I can't pass a complete model object like this.

Comment: Instead of passing an object, you pass something that identifies the object. Then the detail page looks up that object in a collection. See LoadAnimal method in code snippet in the example in docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes. That uses a string key. You might instead use any key into a dictionary (often done with database data that has an id field unique to each object), or an index into a list or array.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass objects through as a Dictionary.

For example if this is the data object you want to send:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Set the query property on the view model of the page:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Person), nameof(Person))]
public partial class DetailViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    Person person;
}
```

Assuming your page constructor looks something like this so it will automatically set the value on your context:

```
public partial class DetailView : ContentPage
{
    public DetailView(DetailViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
}
```

Then when you navigate to the page, pass the object in a dictionary:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DetailView), typeof(DetailView));
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailView), {
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
        [nameof(Person)] = person
    });
```

Now you can access your object in bindings:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Person.Name}"/>
<Label Text="{Binding Person.Age}"/>
```

P.S. Notice the use of `nameof` to avoid hard coded strings.

Comment: I think this Shell version is for MAUI, as I did't find any "GoToAsync()" method that receives dictionary as parameter fro Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can user stored preferences if your json is complex like:

```
   private async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        var jsonstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

        //Clear the shared preferences in case there is any
        Preferences.Clear();

        //Store your complex json on a shared preference
        Preferences.Set("Data", jsonstr);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailsPage));
       
       
    }
```

On the details page where you retrieve your data you can have the following code:

```
            bool hasKey = Preferences.ContainsKey("Data");
            var content = Preferences.Get("Data", string.Empty);

            Details details = hasKey ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(content) : null;
```

Comment: I used your similar logic but I have placed Parameters in the AppShell created so I can access from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small example for your reference.

In the sending class, you can pass parameters like `$"AferPage?param={param}"`.

Here is the sending code:

```
public partial class BeforePage : ContentPage
{
    public BeforePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string param = myEntry.Text;
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"AferPage?param={param}");//like this
    }
}
```

Here is the receiving class code(Implements IQueryAttributable interface):

```
public partial class AferPage : ContentPage, IQueryAttributable
{
    public string param  {get;set;}
    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, string> query)
    {
        param = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(query["param"]);
        receive.Text = param;
    }
    public AferPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem solved？

Comment: this solution wont work with large string eg. > 500 chars

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft.Json you can:

**In List View:**

```
var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject([Model]);
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof([DetailsViewPage])}?Param={jsonStr }");
```

**In Details View Page:**

Add QueryProperty:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Param), nameof(Param))]
```

Convert to Model again:

```
var bonusesFilterData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<[Model]>(Param);
```

A solution is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwnEpiJd0I8

Comment: This doesn't work with long json strings